# Как сделать таймер времени на сайте?

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите как прикрутить к php javascript . Есть код и он работает, как к нему прикрутить таймер времени javascript такого авто обновления чтоб обновлять время и и сделать активную/не активную  ссылку

внизу даю скрин увидел винтернете это такая крутилка видео
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
time_table.dat такого вида

```
1|text|link|04|12|2018|10:00:00|9:55:00|10:30:00| 
2|text|link|04|12|2018|16:00:00|16:55:00|17:30:00| 
3|text|link|04|12|2018|19:00:00|18:55:00|19:30:00| 

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');//timzone


    $data =  file("time_table.dat");

  foreach($data as $rows) {

    $elem = explode("|", $rows);
    if (!strripos($rows, "|")) continue;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$met = $elem[3].'-'.$elem[4].'-'.$elem[5].' '.$elem[7];
$metTS = strtotime($met);
//echo strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", $metTS).'  ';
//echo strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S");
 $sub = $metTS - time();


$sub = abs($sub);
$days = (int)($sub / (24*60*60));
$hours = (int)(($sub - $days * 24 * 60 * 60) / (60*60));
$min = (int)(($sub - $days * 24 * 60 *60 - $hours * 60 * 60) / 60);
$sec = $sub - $days * 24 * 60 *60 - $hours * 60 * 60 - $min * 60;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       $start = $elem[7];
       $end = $elem[8];
       $enter = '';
     $cur_time = strftime('%H:%M:%S', time());  

     if ($cur_time > $start && $cur_time < $end){
     $enter = '<a href="'.$elem[2].'" target="_blank">Активная</a></div>';
     }else{
     $enter = '<a href="#">Неактивная</a>';
     }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

echo'<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">

  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center"  width="150">
        '.$elem[3].'/'.$elem[4].'/'.$elem[5].'-'.$elem[6].'<br>
    '.$elem[1].'
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center"  width="150">   
       '. $hours.':'. $min.':'. $sec.'
        <br>'. $enter .'
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из вашего описания я понял, что вы хотите чего-то вроде:

```
echo <<<EOF
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, 1000);
</script>
EOF;
```

Но боюсь, что это не совсем то, что вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: нечто такое но чуть не такое

Comment: Было бы лучше, что-бы вы ответили чуть поконкретнее: что именно не так. Может быть я смогу дать вам конкретное объяснение.

Comment: потому что дергает всю страницу

Comment: нужно обновлять вот эту часть

Comment: `    <td valign="top" align="center"  width="150">   
       '. $hours.':'. $min.':'. $sec.'
        <br>'. $enter .'
    </td>`

Comment: нужно как на скрите считать время до открытия а потом считать время до закрытия ссылки

Comment: я нашел код к этому скрину только там много кода и не могу разобраться

Comment: В общем для решения этой задачи вам надо:
 - Передать нужные данные на клиент. Это можно сделать с помощью ajax, через coockie ну или с помощью варварского метода:
```<script>
var data = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;
</script>```

Comment: Потом используя `setInterval` редактировать нужные элементы получив к ним доступ при помощи `document.querySelector`:
`setInterval(function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('td.timer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Нарисовать содержимое тэга к примеру время';
}, 1000);`

Comment: И уже по истечении времени получить ссылку с помощью `ajax` или запустить перезагрузку страницы с помощью `window.location`.

Comment: Извините, но я уж не буду писать решение проблемы за вас. Тем более, что даже если я сделаю это, то это получиться тот же `много кода`. Я надеюсь, я не оскорблю вас если скажу, что вам очень не хватает знаний JavaScript.

Comment: поэтому и спрашиваю что не хватает

Comment: для себя шото мудрю